# Searching xmls with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

How would I use powershell to find the paths in this XML?  For example, I need to find the Path for the Application/Name = PSTest AND Environment/Name = DEMO

Here is the sample XML:

```
    <Applications>
        <Application>
            <Name>PSTest</Name>
            <Environment>
                <Name>DEMO</Name>
                <BuildPath>C:\TEST\TEST</BuildPath>
                <Path>C:\TEST\DEMO\PSTest|C:\TEST\DEMO1\PSTest</Path>
                <BackupPath>C:\TEST\Backup</BackupPath>
            </Environment>
            <Environment>
                <Name>PROD</Name>
                <BuildPath>C:\TEST\DEMO</BuildPath>
                <Path>C:\TEST\PROD\PSTest|C:\TEST\PROD1\PSTest</Path>
                <BackupPath>C:\TEST\Backup\PROD</BackupPath>
            </Environment>
        </Application>  
        <Application>
            <Name>PSTestTwo</Name>
            <Environment>
                <Name>DEMO</Name>
                <BuildPath>C:\TEST\TEST</BuildPath>
                <Path>C:\TEST\DEMO\PSTestTwo|C:\TEST\DEMO1\PSTestTwo</Path>
                <BackupPath>C:\TEST\Backup</BackupPath>
            </Environment>
            <Environment>
                <Name>PROD</Name>
                <BuildPath>C:\TEST\DEMO</BuildPath>
                <Path>C:\TEST\PROD\PSTestTwo|C:\TEST\PROD1\PSTestTwo</Path>
                <BackupPath>C:\TEST\Backup\PROD</BackupPath>
            </Environment>
        </Application>  
    </Applications>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) strings to find and select nodes:

```
$oXml = [Xml](Get-Content "infile.xml" | Out-String)
$sXPath = '//Application[Name = "PSTest"]/Environment[Name = "DEMO"]'
$sPath = ($oXml.SelectSingleNode($sXPath)).Path
$sPath
```

Keep in mind that, unlike PowerShell itself, XPath is case-sensitive.

Comment: Nice answer, was about to suggest something similar. I would probably do `$oXml.SelectSingleNode('//Application[Name = "PSTest"]/Environment[Name = "DEMO"]').Path`, easier to read

Comment: Which reminded me about how bad I am at dealing with XML. ) Updated the answer, thanks!